# Normal PSU voltages?

Tags: power-supply, freeze

So i've been having some freezes here and there. After checking out my temps (normal), my memory (ran memtest x86 for 3 hours with no problems) and a cpu stress test (also, no problems), I decided to check my voltages using Speedfan. Here are the results:

Vcore: 1.18V

+12V: 5.23V

AVcc: 3.30V

COREA: 2.35V

COREB: 1.9V

+3.3V: 3.3V

+5V: 5.54V

+12V: 9.54V (This is my concern area)

-12V: -12.29V

-5V: -6.05V (This as well)


I don't think this is normal, correct? I'm running a 650W Corsair PSU into a Q6600 running at stock speeds, on an EVGA 780i SLI FTW motherboard, with a Geforce260GTX 218-core also running at stock speeds. Could this account for my random freezes?

## Edit 1

In Speedfan, it's testing the Winbond W83627DHG and LM78 chips (whatever those are). I'll check with my BIOS and see what it's reporting in a second.

## Edit 2

Bios readings:

CPU Core: 1.28V

CPU FSB: 1.19V

Memory: 1.9V

+3.3V: 3.28V

+3.3V Dual: 3.28V (yea I don't know the difference either)

+12V: 11.98V

+5V: 4.91V

Vbat: 3.08V (another reading I'm not gonna pretend I know anything about)

## Edit 3: More Info

For those of you not willing to read the comments, here's a quoted version of some other things probably related to my issue:

"*I know that all too well. It started out as my computer freezing when I would be playing certain games (SW:TOR and LA Noire do this very effectively. Skyrim and Fallout not so much). I had my video card and cpu under monitor the last few times I was playing those games, but nothing seemed out of the ordinary. I then opened up my case to do some checking of the power cables and to see if I had any puffy capacitors. Everything checked out okay. I left the computer without power for about 3-4 hours. When I plugged it back in, however, it started showing signs of sluggishness. The symptoms were many: It took a while to read my drives (froze while reading an HDD once), then when it did start up, it froze for a bit, then reset my video card driver. Then it started freezing and being really slow in general, a lot more than usual. I decided to let it rest with power for a while and see if that (somehow) fixed things. I slept and returned 8 hours later to find those other issues had went away (only a couple hiccups relating to those since then). Now we're back to the normal freezing. I have a weird issue, I know. I think it's my mobo.*"

Comment: yes concern, yes could. did you look in the bios monitor also? go to speedfan, hit Configure button, go to voltage tab, and put in your question what the chip is that speedfan is reading.  you cannot be positive about the readings.  a voltmeter (even a cheaper one) can be put on a molex to confirm.

Comment: so WHEN do you get freezes?  if there was any real issue with power, between the bios , and the os , and it was that bad, your video card when pushed to do some 3d stuff would hard lock or slap the whole computer off. playing a game using the 3d and the cpu , it should die quickly :-)  the speedfan seems to be reading a chip that should show right, the winbond reads close here.  but you know a person can go replace crasy  believing softwares and errors.

Comment: I know that all too well. It started out as my computer freezing when I would be playing certain games (SW:TOR and LA Noire do this very effectively. Skyrim and Fallout not so much). I had my video card and cpu under monitor the last few times I was playing those games, but nothing seemed out of the ordinary. 

I then opened up my case to do some checking of the power cables and to see if I had any puffy capacitors. Everything checked out okay. I left the computer without power for about 3-4 hours. When I plugged it back in, however, it started (cont)

Comment: Showing signs of sluggishness. The symptoms were many: It took a while to read my drives (froze while reading an HDD once), then when it did start up, it froze for a bit, then reset my video card driver. Then it started freezing and being really slow in general, a lot more than usual. I decided to let it rest with power for a while and see if that (somehow) fixed things. I slept and returned 8 hours later to find those other issues had went away (only a couple hiccups relating to those since then). Now we're back to the normal freezing. I have a weird issue, I know. I think it's my mobo.

Comment: ok a voltmeter and a IR temp probe :-) I would software monitor the temps and fans and voltages, that is already not going well via softwares :-(  Supercool everything by jacking up the fans esp. the gpu fans , mabey temprarily place the big box fan on the side of the case, and run some wicked test software, like intel burn, furmark, OCCT , and see what happens to the numbers.  must find good monitors that work with the board first.

Comment: I have ran all my fans on high (if I was able to adjust the fans) and it still froze. My GPU stayed at around 60 degrees Celsius under full load, and my other temps stayed around 55 degrees Celsius when the freezes happened. I have a multimeter but I don't know how to use it to check the voltages directly. Any tips on that?

Comment: Set voltmeter to DC volts, if not autoranging set the range, put probes only in slots for reading volts not amps.  test probes on simple battery to be sure , then shove the probes into a molex socket carefully.  Biggest problems that could occur, is shorting because it set to amps, or shorting by crossing up the pins when inserted.

Comment: @Psycogeek Shorting out my equipment, eh? Ouch. I'll go fetch a more detailed write-up. Should I test the main board molex connector or the CPU power connector?

Comment: test the 12v  and 5v on a loose molex for a hd (or something), get it all stable (forgot to mention not grounding to metal case). Run a load test.  If those 2 voltages hold fine, then it probably is not a PSU problem.  While in there, power off, pull the AC plug and slide All the power connectors On and off 2 times, to sluff off any oxidations. Then you can ignore the PSU as being the problem.